# dumping dictionary with yaml.dump doesn't write special characters to file with "with open()" in python3

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I want to dump a dictionary to a YAML file but my umlauts get messed up.

Here is the code:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
dictUsed = 'Testdurchführung'

with open(r'C:\Users\somepath', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(dictUsed, stream=outfile)
```

The output is for example:

```
Testdurchf�hrung
```

I want the ouptut in the file to be this:

```
Testdurchführung
```

However, when I use this it works:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(dictUsed, sys.stdout)
```

Output to console is:

```
Testdurchführung
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: how are you retrieving the output?

Comment: Does it give the wrong output when you load it again in Python (if so please show the Python code you're using to do that), or are you looking at the file it writes in some file viewer (which may be reading it with the wrong encoding)?

Comment: Could you use the `errors="strict"` argument of the open method. This will tell you when there are encoding errors.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I look at it in Atom (text editor)

Comment: @aJazz check that atom is using the correct encoding. You should probably use an encoding explicitly when you create the file, e.g `open(r'C:\Users\somepath', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @aJazz. FIrst make sure you in clude `yaml = YAML()` in your first code example and then change the `'w'` to `'wb'` as you want to write a binvary file with the (standard) UTF-8 output and not a text file, especially not on Windows.

Comment: @Anthon thank you! 'wb' did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file on Windows using `'w'` it will write a text file, but ruamel.yaml by default writes a binary UTF-8 encoded file.

On `sys.stdout` that normally works (unless your terminal doesn't support UTF-8), so you don't see the problem there.

You should either open the file for output using:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\somepath', 'wb') as outfile:
```

or use a `pathlib.Path` instance:

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\somepath')
yaml.dump(dictUsed, p)
```